# Class for object analysis

Tags: php, oop

currently designs classes that are designed to analyze routes made by a vehicle.

I need, for example, to calculate the price of fuel on individual sections and then sum them up as, for example, a monthly route.

There is one fuel rate for the whole month.

I planned it this way:

```
class FullRoute{
   public function setFuelCost($cost){}

   public function addRoute(Route $route){}

   public function getDistance(){
    // sum routes distance
   }
}

class Route{
   public function setFuelCost($cost){}

   public function setDistance($distance){}

   public function getDistance(){}

   public function getCost(){
        //returns cost of route;
   }

}
```

I wonder now if this is a good approach, there are more methods - this is just an example.

From the FullRoute class I would like to take a summary, that's why I added the setFuelCost method - the summary is to return the distance counted from all episodes but also the criteria (as the fuel rate - that's why this method).

Maybe someone solves a similar problem and has some suggestions on how to design it?
Thanks for the help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe you can try something like this:

```
class Route {

   public function setDistance($distance_miles) {

   }

   public function getDistance() {

   }

   public function getCost($price_per_galon, $miles_per_galon) {

   }

   public function getFuelUsed($miles_per_galon) {

   }
}

class RoutesSummary {

   public function __construct($price_per_galon, $miles_per_galon) {

   }

   public function addRoute(Route $route) {

   }

   public function getTotalDistance(){
     // sum routes distances
   }

   public function getTotalCost() {
     $cost = 0;

     foreach($this->routes as $route) {
       $cost += $route->getCost(
          $this->price_per_galon, 
          $this->miles_per_galon
       );
     }

     return $cost;
   }

   public function getTotalFuelUsed() {
     // sum routes fuel used
   }

   public function getDetail() {
     // return list of route costs
   }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer!
I forgot to add that I need to get details from the summary class, i.e. how much fuel cost was on the particular route, how many liters were used, etc., that's why I added setters and getters for the Route class

Comment: The models I gave you allow you to compute cost per route and total.

Comment: I added an example

Comment: Thanks, it seems to be a good solution.

I am still worried about one thing. If at the presentation layer I would like to display the following details:

The sum of kilometers on the route
The total fuel cost

Then list each route how many kilometers it was and the cost.

Should I get these values already calculated from the RoutesSummary class as an array?

I was planning to use this in the echo style Route-> getCost () - would I have to recalculate it by giving parameters to the function?

Comment: You can present the detail by iterating over each route and getting the cost passing the price and mpg parameters. Or If not you you can add a detail($price_per_galon, $miles_per_galon) function to RoutesSummary that returns an array with the individual route costs. Then you get all the summary data directly from the summary object

Comment: Thanks, I'm still wondering if, after calling $route-> getCost ($ price_per_galon, $ miles_per_galon) in the RoutesSummary object, save the calculated cost in the $route object as the cost parameter (Route-> cost). 

Add the getRoutes method to the RoutesSummary class, which will return the already calculated $route objects, and then I could get the calculated values in presentation?Is this a wrong thinking?

Comment: I updated the code. Just pass the summary object to the presentation. I added the parameters to the summary constructor so that they are fixed for all the parts of the report.

Answer (score 0):

Additionally you could utilise [SplSubject](http://php.net/manual/en/class.splsubject.php) and [SplObserver](http://php.net/manual/en/class.splobserver.php) Design Pattern.

Which will allow you to inject your RouteSection (SplObserver) into the Route (SplSubject) and update the report in one go without having getters and setters in both classes.

And a single instance `$route` which your be calling to get your report/datas.

Here is an example, which I think covers what your after:

```
<?php

/**
 * Route
 */
class Route implements \SplSubject {
    private $data;
    private $observers = array();
    private $content;

    public function __construct($data) {
        $this->data = $data;
        $this->report = [];
        $this->total_cost = 0;
        $this->total_distance = 0;
    }

    // getters
    public function getRoute() {
        return $this->data['name'];
    } 

    public function getDistance() {
        return $this->data['distance'];
    }

    public function getReport() {
        return $this->report;
    }    

    public function getTotalCost() {
        return number_format($this->total_cost, 2);
    }

    public function getTotalDistance() {
        return $this->total_distance;
    }

    // run
    public function run() {
        $this->notify();
    }

    // spl pub/sub methods
    public function attach(\SplObserver $observer) {
        $this->observers[] = $observer;
    }

    public function detach(\SplObserver $observer) {
        $key = array_search($observer, $this->observers, true);
        if ($key) {
            unset($this->observers[$key]);
        }
    }

    public function notify() {
        foreach ($this->observers as $value) {
            $value->update($this);
        }
    }
}

/**
* RouteSection
*/
class RouteSection implements SplObserver {
    private $vehicle;
    private $driver;

    public function __construct($vehicle, $driver) {
        $this->vehicle = $vehicle;
        $this->driver = $driver;
    }

    public function update(\SplSubject $subject) {
        $subject->report[$this->vehicle['id']] = [
            'route'    => $subject->getRoute(),
            'vehicle'  => $this->vehicle,
            'driver'   => $this->driver,
            'distance' => $subject->getDistance(),
            'cost'     => $subject->getDistance() * $this->vehicle['ppm']
        ];

        $subject->total_distance += $subject->report[$this->vehicle['id']]['distance'];
        $subject->total_cost += $subject->report[$this->vehicle['id']]['cost'];
    }
}

// define some drivers
$drivers[] = ['id' => 1, 'name' => 'Lawrence'];
$drivers[] = ['id' => 2, 'name' => 'Paul'];
$drivers[] = ['id' => 3, 'name' => 'Simon'];

// define some vehicles (ppm could be defined single value)
$vehicles[] = ['id' => 1, 'name' => 'Truck A', 'ppm' => 0.001];
$vehicles[] = ['id' => 2, 'name' => 'Truck B', 'ppm' => 0.003];
$vehicles[] = ['id' => 3, 'name' => 'Truck C', 'ppm' => 0.006];

// define route
$route = new Route([
    'id' => 1,
    'name' => 'San José',
    'distance' => 220
]);

// create & attach RouteSection with vehicle and driver
foreach ($drivers as $key => $driver) {
    $route->attach(new RouteSection(
        $vehicles[$key], // vehicle
        $driver          // driver
    ));
}

// run route
$route->run();

//
echo 'Total Distance: '.$route->getTotalDistance().PHP_EOL;

//
echo 'Total Cost: '.$route->getTotalCost().PHP_EOL;

echo PHP_EOL;

// get report
print_r($route->getReport());
```

https://3v4l.org/siekY

**Result:**

```
Total Distance: 660
Total Cost: 2.20

Array
(
    [1] => Array
        (
            [route] => San José
            [vehicle] => Array
                (
                    [id] => 1
                    [name] => Truck A
                    [ppm] => 0.001
                )

            [driver] => Array
                (
                    [id] => 1
                    [name] => Lawrence
                )

            [distance] => 220
            [cost] => 0.22
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [route] => San José
            [vehicle] => Array
                (
                    [id] => 2
                    [name] => Truck B
                    [ppm] => 0.003
                )

            [driver] => Array
                (
                    [id] => 2
                    [name] => Paul
                )

            [distance] => 220
            [cost] => 0.66
        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [route] => San José
            [vehicle] => Array
                (
                    [id] => 3
                    [name] => Truck C
                    [ppm] => 0.006
                )

            [driver] => Array
                (
                    [id] => 3
                    [name] => Simon
                )

            [distance] => 220
            [cost] => 1.32
        )

)
```